# How to make combination of characters to form a word in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I need various words of the length n and at each position/index there can m different elements.

For Example  n = 5

For the first position elements allowed are : H,Y,U,B,N

For the second position elements allowed are : E,S,D

For the third position elements allowed are : L,O,P

For the fourth position elements allowed are : L,O,P

For the fifth position elements allowed are : O,K,L

So the various words that can be formed are: HELLO , YELLK , BDPOK etc.

What could be an efficient way to find out all the possible words in a kind of efficient way in Java?

Comment: What's your existing inefficient implementation that you need to improve on?

Comment: @RichardTingle I am yet to write any code yet. Whatever was coming to my mind was highly inefficient, so thought of gathering some suggestions before I start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think choosing each character from each string recursively, and moving to the next string is the simplest way, I implemented java code, I added some comments, if anything isn't clear don't hesitate to ask .

```
    static String s[] = {"HYUBN", "ESD", "LOP", "LOP", "OKL"};
    static ArrayList<String> comb; // arraylist is going to hold results.

    static void dfs(String x,int i) {
        if(i == s.length) {   // there is no more string that can be generated
            comb.add(x); // save the found string
            return;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<s[i].length();j++)  // for each character in the current string
            dfs(x+s[i].charAt(j),i+1); // take the current character and move to the next string
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        comb = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs("",0);
        for(String x:comb) out.print(x + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to find all the possible words would be to take a statistics and probability class, and explore how Combinations and Permutations are calculated.  There are 5*3*3*3*3 combinations to your proposed example.

Yes, Java would be an effective way of yielding all the combinations to your problem, but other languages would work too.  You could also do it with paper and pencil, but you might want a computer depending on how many combinations you have to deal with.

Good Luck, and the community looks forward to seeing the example code you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency can depend largely on how the dictionary of possible words is organized.  If it is organized alphabetically (in a Java array or **ArrayList**), then checking for valid combinations as they are built (left-to-right) would rule out a large number of checks.  For example, checking "ND..." and finding no word starting with it will save time by *not* checking NDLLO, NDLLK, NDLLL, NDLOO...

A Java **TreeMap** can be an even better data structure for incremental search, but could take longer to construct and more memory than a simple ordered array if the source of words is ordered and we are simply adding them to an array from a file that contains all the words.

TreeMap and binary search on an ordered ArrayList, would each take O(log n) time, and could rule out words as soon as initial letters don't match a possible.  A very thorough dictionary containing abbreviations like "NDA" would check more, a smaller dictionary may only need 1 or 2 checks per 2-letter combination (note there is no point checking single letters since single letters always start a word).

Further refinement could be to hash the initial few (or more) letters of every word in the word set (Using a Java **HashMap**, for example) for O(n) lookup on initial starts, trading memory for more speed.  If we hashed all incremental possibilities (HE, HEL, HELL, HELLO, YE, YEL, ... which is a large memory cost) then every incremental check would be O(n), where n is the number of incremental checks needed to rule out words.

More refinement: if we have control of the organization of the word set, we could order the words by a different order of letters using modulo of a prime number:

```
"HELLO" rearranged by mod 7, for example would be:  "HLOEL"
```

This could give better performance because it removes some of the clustering that naturally occurs in language around common prefixes.  Higher prime numbers would give better (flatter) distribution.  Combine this with a hash on the first n lookups, and we will have performance vary between O(n) and O(log n).